# ¿Es posible asignar a un button html, un value para después recuperar el value en una variable php sin utilizar form?

Tags: php

¿Es posible o cómo sería para poder asignar a un button (que es un enlace) un value por ejemplo value="tomates" para despues en recuperar ese valor en una variable php ejemplo $valor?

Ejemplo:
En página1.php tener un botón:

```
<a href="pagina2.php"><button  type="button" value="tomates">Página principal</button></a>
```

Y después en página2.php recuperar el valor:

```
echo $valor;
```

¿Es obligatorio utilizar un form y pasar mediante post para recuperar el valor con un $_POST...? El tema es que no quiero un input en el que el usuario tenga que introducir un valor, sino tener un valor predefinido a ese botón.

Comment: Según el estándar html, un elemento `a` no debe contener elementos interactivos (como un botón u otro enlace). Si estás usando un enlace, ¿por qué no pasar el valor en la url y leerlo desde el `$_GET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el estándar html, un elemento `a` no debe contener elementos interactivos (como un botón u otro enlace). Eso hace que el código compartido no sea válido y su interpretación puede variar de navegador a navegador.

Si estás usando un enlace, ¿por qué no pasar el valor en la url y leerlo desde el `$_GET`? Como dices que el valor es fijo y el usuario no lo va a cambiar, no pongas el valor en un botón, ponlo en la url del enlace:

```
<a href="pagina2.php?valor=tomates">enlace</a>
```

Luego en PHP lo podrías leer desde `$_GET` o `$_REQUEST` del siguiente modo:

```
$mivalor = $_GET["valor"];
```